# How can I concatenate combined two queries?

Tags: mysql

I have created three tables and my query is working fine but I am trying to concatenate two columns but I am getting error.

This code below gets info from 3 different tables

```
(SELECT 
     programme_date, prog_start_time, walk_title, guide_fname, guide_sname
 FROM 
     programme, walk, guide)
```

This code concat is working.

```
SELECT CONCAT(guide_fname, guide_sname) AS guide_fullname
FROM guide
```

I would love to combine all in one query for the two query. Anyone could help please?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: look at using PRIMARY keys, and INNER JOIN or any other JOIN.. I think that's what you need. Your question is hard to understand.

Comment: I'd suggest you provide in your question the failing query you've tried to run. Also knowing the structure of your tables would help.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  All I need is to concatinate guide_fname and guide_sname in a field call a fullname

(SELECT programme_date, prog_start_time, walk_title, guide_fname, guide_sname
FROM programme, walk, guide)

Comment: `SELECT programme_date, prog_start_time, walk_title, CONCAT(guide_fname, guide_sname) AS guide_fullname
FROM programme, walk, guide` ?

Comment: The obvious gap in knowledge is too great to be addressed here.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna go and assume the structure and relationship of your tables.

You need to use `INNER JOIN` to join the tables together using their `PRIMARY KEY` and related `FOREIGN KEY` columns.
Also I recommend using [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead of `CONCAT` as it handles `NULL` values better.

```
SELECT programme_date, prog_start_time, walk_title, CONCAT_WS(' ', guide_fname, guide_lname) as fullname
FROM programme AS p
INNER JOIN walk AS w ON w.programme_id = p.id
INNER JOIN guide AS g ON g.id = w.guide_id
```